# How is correctness of the input checked when hash has a salt in it? (Different hashes - the same input)

Tags: hash, cryptography

By adding salt to the hash – an element of randomness that will make the same input create a different hash, but still usable to check the correctness of the input when entered again.

And how is that?

How is that possible to check the corectness of the input, when the same input will create different hash? (hash with salt)

Comment: you take the putative input and the salt, compute the hash, and compare it to the existing hash. If they match, the input is correct.

Comment: @JamesKPolk but the existing hash and new hash isn't exactly the same - "the same input create a different hash"

Comment: When doing the comparison you don't create a new salt, you use the salt that is stored with the hash.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.